# scsi err codes and translation to strings

Tags: c, linux, char, int

I wonder what would be the best way to map Error codes to strings for instance in the SCSI protocol the errors are always returned as numbers. like this:

```
00h GOOD
02h CHECK CONDITION
04h CONDITION MET
08h BUSY
18h RESERVATION CONFLICT
28h TASK SET FULL
30h ACA ACTIVE
40h TASK ABORTED
```

I wonder what would be the best way to translate these codes on the fly to there string counterpart? I thought about doing an array or something but Ig would have to make an array of length 40h even though I wont use most of the indices. So is the best way to just make a function which takes the number as input and returns a string?

Comment: Hard to tell if it's the "best" way, but it is one way that looks ok to me.

Comment: I suspect those are not actual error codes, but bit field definitions (or combinations of bits in a couple cases) - you might sometimes get a status code that doesn't exactly match any of those numbers because it's a combination of them...

Comment: I dont think so. It seems that the other error codes are either reserved or are vendor specific. There is no mention of what you are thinking in the scsi protocol. At least I have never seen it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example on how to define some codes as macros and then using another macro function to get the string value of the macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define GOOD 0
#define CHECK_CONDITON 2
#define CONDITION_MET 4

/* more codes here */

#define STR_VALUE(CODE) #CODE

void print_scsi(int code) {
  char *scsi_string;

  switch (code) {
    case GOOD: 
      scsi_string = STR_VALUE(GOOD); break;
    case CHECK_CONDITON: 
      scsi_string = STR_VALUE(CHECK_CONDITON); break;
    case CONDITION_MET: 
      scsi_string = STR_VALUE(CONDITION_MET); break;

    /* ... */
  }
  printf("code: %d string: %s\n", code, scsi_string);
}

int main(void) {
  print_scsi(0);
  print_scsi(2);
  print_scsi(4);
}
```

Running this gives:

```
code: 0 string: GOOD
code: 2 string: CHECK_CONDITON
code: 4 string: CONDITION_MET
```

If the list of codes is long, define the macros in a separate header file, along with `STR_VALUE` and include it your main program.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit tricky but you can try to use a [X-macro](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387).

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SCSI_ERR_TABLE                          \
    X(GOOD,            "good",            0x00) \
    X(CHECK_CONDITION, "check condition", 0x02) \
    X(CONDITION_MET,   "condition met",   0x04) \
    X(BUSY,            "busy",            0x08) \

#define X(ERR, STR, ID) ERR = ID,
enum {
    SCSI_ERR_TABLE
};
#undef X


#define X(ERR, STR, ID) {.id = ID, .string = STR},
static const struct {
    int id;
    char string[32];
} scsi_err_strings[] = { SCSI_ERR_TABLE };
#undef X

const char *scsi_get_err_string(int error)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(scsi_err_strings) / sizeof(scsi_err_strings[0]); i++) {
        if (scsi_err_strings[i].id == error)
            return scsi_err_strings[i].string;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main(void)
{
    int err;

    err = CHECK_CONDITION;
    printf("%d -> %s\n", err, scsi_get_err_string(err));

    err = BUSY;
    printf("%d -> %s\n", err, scsi_get_err_string(err));

    return 0;
}
```